# Diacritics in search function case sensitive

Tags: python, django, search

I have a search function in my Django app:

```
#search
def search(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        result = Post.objects.filter(title__contains=searched)
        return render(request, 'blog/searched.html', {'searched':searched, 'result':result})
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/searched.html',{})
```

Problem is, when I search the following, I get the following results:

```
Zaštita -> I get 'Zaštita' result
zaštita -> I get 'Zaštita' result
Čep -> I get 'Čep' result
čep -> I get nothing (diacritic letter in the first place, case sensitive)
```

Only if diacritic letter in the first place the search is case sensitive.

Input page HTML:

```
<div class="content-section">
              <form class="d-flex" method=POST action="{% url 'search' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input class="form-control me-2 mr-2" type="search" placeholder="Title" aria-label="Search" name="searched">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: 1)To make a search it is better not to use a `POST request` instead use `GET request` (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1) 2)try this `result = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=searched)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`__icontains`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) to make a case insenstive search. Normally searching is however done through a GET request: POST requests are usually used for state-changing actions, or when submitting sensitive data.

You thus can search with:

```
def search(request):
    searched = request.GET.get('searched')
    result = Post.objects.all()
    if searched is not None:
        result = result.filter(title__icontains=searched)
    return render(request, 'blog/searched.html', {'searched':searched, 'result':result})
```

---

> **Note**: While using the [**`__icontains`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) produces results for text, this often is still a poor way to search, since it will only fetch items with the exact string. Usually one uses solutions like [*Elastic*](https://www.elastic.co/) or [*Solr*](https://solr.apache.org/), or one can uses *PostgreSQL*'s [**`__search`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup).

Comment: I tried, but each time I get nothing with 'searched = request.GET.get('searched')'. print(searched) is always None. Why so? 
My input is:
```
<input class="form-control me-2 mr-2" type="search" placeholder="Tekst naslova" aria-label="Search" name="searched">
```
And only if diacritic symbol (like č,ž,š) is first letter, only then seach is case sensitive.

Comment: The `<form>` should have `method="get"`.

Comment: Fixed, but results are still the same. When I search 'Čep' with 'čep' I get no results. But when I search with 'Čep' I get 'Čep'. Search is not case sensitive for non diacritic symbols.